# SQL: select most recent event of certain type

Tags: sql, sqlite

My database (sqlite3), has two tables with the following schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE log(d date, usr text, tag text, bytes int);
CREATE TABLE valid(tag text, filesize int);
```

Let's say I have the following sample data:

```
      d    | usr  |  tag | bytes
--------------------------------
2012-01-19 | bob  |  foo | 990
2012-01-18 | bob  |  foo | 1000
2012-01-17 | joe  |  bar | 2000
2012-01-16 | joe  |  bar | 1800
2012-01-15 | joe  |  baz | 0


tag  | size
-----------
foo  | 1000
bar  | 2000
```

I would like to retrieve a list of the most recent events that resulted in a user failing to access all the bytes in a valid file.  In the example above, the select should yield 2012-01-19 | bob | foo | 990.

Right now, I'm using two select statements to get the results.  The first gets the most recent event per user, and the second checks whether all the bytes were accessed.

```
CREATE VIEW tmp AS 
SELECT * FROM log JOIN (SELECT max(d) AS maxd, usr FROM log GROUP BY usr) AS 
tmplog ON (tmplog.usr=log.usr and tmplog.maxd=log.d);

SELECT usr,d FROM tmp 
WHERE tag IN (SELECT tag FROM valid) AND bytes NOT IN (SELECT size FROM valid);
```

Is there a way to do this with one select or more efficiently?

**Update:**

In the example above, the query shouldn't retrieve user "joe" since his most recent log entry shows a complete file being accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the most recent `d` per `usr` and `tag` (where `bytes < filesize`), then select those `log` entries matching those most recent `d/usr/tag` values:

```
    SELECT log.*
      FROM log
INNER JOIN (    SELECT usr, tag, MAX(d) AS d
                  FROM log
              GROUP BY 1, 2) most_recent
        ON most_recent.usr = log.usr
            AND
           most_recent.tag = log.tag
            AND
           most_recent.d = log.d
INNER JOIN valid
        ON log.tag = valid.tag
     WHERE log.bytes < valid.filesize;
```

Comment: This returns "joe" in the example above, but I'd like to exclude that since his most recent access was successful.

Comment: A small tweak to the query got things working. I removed 'tag' from the second select, and its associated comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT log.* FROM
  log
  JOIN
  (SELECT usr,tag,MAX(d)
   FROM log
   GROUP BY usr,tag) log2
  USING(usr,tag)
  JOIN valid ON (log.tag = valid.tag)
  WHERE d=`max(d)` AND bytes != valid.filesize
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
log.*
From log
Inner Join valid On valid.tag = log.tag
Where log.bytes < valid.size Order By log.d Desc
```

Should work, but doesn't look very efficient to me.

It's slightly different in that it will return multiple rows per user if the same user had more than one issue - do you specifically not want this?

Comment: I tried this on a larger dataset, and it only returned one record (the most recent) out of a few that should have been returned.  I would also like only one row per user/file.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can suggest so far:

1. Join `log` and `valid` to get all the rows where `bytes <= size` and to find out `MAX(d)` per `tag`.
2. Join the result set back to `log` on `tag` & `d` to get the entire rows pertaining to the corresponding events.
3. Join again to `valid` to get only the rows where `bytes < size`. That is necessary to filter out the max dates where the bytes matched the size.

This is how the query might look:

```
SELECT
  log.*
FROM log
  INNER JOIN valid ON log.tag = valid.tag AND log.bytes < valid.size
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      log.tag,
      MAX(log.d) AS d
    FROM log
      INNER JOIN valid ON log.tag = valid.tag AND log.bytes <= valid.size
    GROUP BY
      log.tag
  ) last
    ON log.tag = last.tag AND log.d = last.d
```

The above assumes that on any date there can only be one event for particular tag. Otherwise the schema presented in the question doesn't allow one to determine which event was the latest one if more than one happen on the same date.

Comment: This returned "Error: ambiguous column name: tag", so I used log.tag in the second select.  After that, I only got one result, the most recent one, but not any of the others.

Comment: @Octave: Yes, that's because I forgot to add `GROUP BY ...`. Sorry, updated my answer.

Comment: I think the query doesn't consider if the most recent event was "good".  In the example data, user "joe" shouldn't be selected.

Comment: @Octave: In that case there should be a way to determine if a certain event for a particular tag was indeed the latest in case more than one event can happen on the same `d`. Assuming presently that the latter will be impossible, I can suggest a change to my present solution. Please see my update.

Comment: You're right.  I simplified my example to include only date, but I'm actually using datetime.  My primary key is (d, usr, tag), and in my system there can't be more than one event of such type.